# How to use an abstract class instead of an interface for a custom component?

Tags: php, yii2

I'm working on a File Manager module for Yii2 where the goal is to provide the user with an option to use different sources for directory browsing, like

- Local Directory
- Dropbox
- One Drive
- Google Drive

To accomplish this, I wrote an interface which will be implemented by different adapters that the user wants to use. For example, here are a few lines of code from the interface with common functions:

```
<?php

namespace buttflattery\filemanager\adapters;

/**
 * File Manager Interface class
 */
interface DirectoryInterface
{

    public function listFolder(string $directory, array $sortParams);

    public function removeFile(string $file);

    public function createFolder(string $folder, string $parentDirectory);

    public function uploadFile(string $file, string $destinationDirectory);

    public function downloadFile(string $zipFile);

    public function renameFile(string $oldFile, string $newFile);

    public function moveFiles(array $filesList, string $destination);

    public function copyFiles(array $files, string $destination);

}
```

I started with the `LocalDirectoryAdapter`; it's attached as a component with the module via a config file,

```
'modules' => [
    'filemanager' => [
        'class' => 'buttflattery\filemanager\Module',
        'components' => [
             'adapter' => [
                 'class' => 'buttflattery\filemanager\adapters\local\LocalDirectoryAdapter',
                 'rootDir' => 'tinyii-uploads'
             ]
        ],
    ],
],
```

It all works fine, until I came across a situation after I started implementing the Dropbox adapter.

There are a couple of methods that will be using exactly the same code. For instance, the `listFolder()` is the same in both `LocalDirectoryAdapter` and `DropoxAdapter`.

The reason is because there is a `FileIndexer` component which queries the file tree and writes it down to a JSON file, and then all the listing and browsing is done via that JSON file by the `FileIndexer` component.

At that point, I figured I needed to change the interface to an `abstract` class, add those methods that are common, and leave those methods as abstract which will need to be implemented specifically to the Directory source I am using. That is where I got puzzled:

The `LocalDirectoryAdapter` class is declared as

```
class LocalDirectoryAdapter extends Component implements DirectoryInterface{
}
```

Once I change the interface to an abstract class, I am bound to use `extend`, and in that case, I cant extend the `yii\base\Component` class.

How can I get around this problem?

Comment: couldn't your abstract class extend it? or perhaps instead of an abstract class, use a Trait

Comment: hmmmmm never thought abt it let me try, i think it should work

Comment: I'd rather keep it an interface. You may use [trait](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) for your listFolder implementation. Things are more flexible with composition than with inheritance.

Comment: yes i would also go for the `trait` thanks @KoalaYeung and james both for your suggestions

Comment: can anyone of you guys post an answer @james koalaYeung so i can mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Trait` instead of an abstract class to handle this common code.  One reason for using a Trait is that it will allow you to keep your class hierarchy  unchanged but also reusing the code that would otherwise be duplicated.

Here's how to inject the trait into your implemented class:

```
<?php
class LocalDirectoryAdapter extends yii\base\Component implements DirectoryInterface{
  use DirectoryTrait;

  public function removeFile(string $file) { }

  public function createFolder(string $folder, string $parentDirectory) { }

  public function uploadFile(string $file, string $destinationDirectory) { }

  public function downloadFile(string $zipFile) { }

  public function renameFile(string $oldFile, string $newFile) { }

  public function moveFiles(array $filesList, string $destination) { }

  public function copyFiles(array $files, string $destination) { }
}
```

And the Trait itself:

```
<?php
trait DirectoryTrait {
  public function listFolder(string $directory, array $sortParams) {
    //implement the listFolder things
  }
}
```

You can even selectively choose to have your adapters use the Trait or not by simply excluding the `use AdapterTrait` line.  Here is a small working example (`trait.php`).  See how `DirectoryAdapterNoTrait` does not use the trait.

```
<?php
interface AdapterInterface {
    public function listFiles(string $dir);
}

trait AdapterTrait {
    public function listFiles(string $dir)
    {
        echo "Doing TRAIT listFiles" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
class DirectoryAdapterTrait extends yii\base\Component implements AdapterInterface {
    use AdapterTrait;
}
class DirectoryAdapterNoTrait extends yii\base\Component implements AdapterInterface {
    public function listFiles(string $dir)
    {
        echo "NOT TRAIT listFiles" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$adapterTrait = new DirectoryAdapterTrait();
$adapterTrait->listFiles("some_dir");

$adapterNoTrait = new DirectoryAdapterNoTrait();
$adapterNoTrait->listFiles("some_dir");

echo PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer james

Answer (score 1):

You can make your abstract adapter extend the `yii\base\Component` then by extending your abstract adapter the child class will also inherit from Component.

For example like this

```
abstract class BaseDirectoryAdapter extends Component
{
}

class LocalDirectoryAdapter extends BaseDirectoryAdapter
{
}
```

But I think it's not a good practice to force usage of your abstract base class.
You don't know what adapters might be implemented in future.

What you can do is to use both. The interface that would define minimal requirements for adapter and abstract base class that would provide standard impelmentations for common methods.

```
interface DirectoryInterface
{
}

abstract class BaseDirectoryAdapter extends Component implements DirectoryInterface
{
}

class LocalDirectoryAdapter extends BaseDirectoryAdapter
{
}
```

This allows you to benefit from implementations in BaseDirectoryAdapter but doesn't force you to use it.

Yii uses this approach, you can for example see it with `yii\db\ActiveRecord`, `yii\db\BaseActiveRecord` and `yii\db\ActiveRecordInterface`.

Comment: Yes it is an option but it would require a lot more changes as compared to using the trait as suggested above by `koala` and `james` under the comments, so i would prefer that but upvoted your answer as it also answers the question and can help someone in future